# How to make a fading hue animation of a static image?

Tags: color, animation, color-conversion, video, animated-gif

Say image A is a static portrait drawing of someone. You'd like to make an animation that has no movement of the artwork, but just alternating re-colorations of the portrait in such a way that it changes the hue of the image with the same smoothness of pulling the Hue slider in an image editor back and forth between, say, red and blue.

Which free software will allow this to be done, ideally without having to lay out each frame between red and blue, one-by-one, as a .gif so maybe .mp4 even?

Comment: Nothing was changed in question content except for 1 word's removal in the title.

Comment: For free software try GIMP.  There's a simple [Colour Cycle animation script here](https://www.deviantart.com/monsoonami/art/GIMP-Color-Cycle-Anim-Script-254616394). You can then export as an animated GIF.  There's a tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lF2Xh-7vk4k

Comment: A fair many video editors have filters that could do this sort of thing as well

Comment: name some and the corresponding tool.

Answer (score 2):

Any non-linear video editor will do. There are several free. Try the first one. Is very lightweight.

[Open Shot](https://www.openshot.org)

This next one has a little weird sub-directory system, but it is reasonably lightweight too.

[VSDC](https://www.videosoftdev.com)

From here, they are overkill for what you need but will get the job done.

[Hit Film Express](https://fxhome.com/product/hitfilm-express) (When downloading move the Price slider to the left)

[Blender](https://www.blender.org/)

[Davinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve/)

Simply put one image on one channel and another on a second channel and choose the **fade-in or fade-out** tool as needed.

Here is a capture from the first option.

<sub>One image over the other and right click</sub>
[image]

There are several ways to do that in each application, so you might need to look at the documentation or google a tutorial.

<sub>One image over the other on the same channel</sub>
[image]

**This will not animate the hue slider. You need to manually prepare the different keyframes or images for the transitions.**

You can also do this on PowerPoint with the dissolve transition between slides.

---

**For the real deal**

Use Blender. It is pretty complicated because **you need to configure a ton of things.** But the basic setup is this:

The red circles are places where you need to pay attention **for your specific question**.

1. Import your image as planes
2. Add a hue node
3. Select a keyframe and fix a hue status (2 again)
4. Add a keyframe and change and fix the hue status
5. Configure your output. You will have an image sequence, which you can export as gif on some other software.

[image]

[image]

Comment: 2 out of the 3 answers here are propagating individual frames one hue at a time  :-/

Comment: No. You define some keyframes. Not all of them. Only let's say changes in hue every 20%. From there you can make the transition of 50 frames if you want.

But the last example is fully automatic. ;-)